# Idiom for "one-after-another"

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Looking for an idiom that describe such situation that one event entails another. I.e., describing mostly for troublesome/negative events that comes one-after-another. "long-tailed"?

For example,

- to explain "Z", then I have to first to explain "Y", which depends on understanding of "X", which builds on top of "W", ...
- or, it's like pulling up a huge carrot -- the more you pull, yet the more it seems are still missing.

I.e., once started, problems come one-after-another. Any idiom for this? Thanks

Comment: Honestly, your two examples don't seem to be the same thing.... particularly, your first example doesn't seem to imply your i.e. statement at the end.

Comment: Also, neither one seems to match your question's Title.

Comment: Guys, you've got to read between the lines what I was asking. If I can precisely describe it, I might not need to ask in the first place. I like Brian's approach when answering, make a guess, and give an answer. After all, there are people who have understood exactly what I was looking for. BTW, the other idiom in my mind when asking the question was "**the tip of the iceberg**", however, I didn't mention that because it stressed on the magnitude of the issue, not the situation that problems come one after another. If you think along this path, then my two examples make perfect sense.

Comment: my two examples make perfect sense, especially the first one. Comment was too long, have to split out the question here -- is there a phrase like ***"when problems come, they come in pairs"***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few commonplaces that might suit your needs:

Let's not get into that subject. It's *a can of worms*.

Don't pull that *thread*, or the whole thing will *unravel*.

Careful, it's *a slippery slope*.

Comment: I like the fabric analogy; but it's not that things will all unravel; it's more as if there's a knot, which the more you try to undo it, _the more entangled it gets._  anyway, +1 for Can of Worms.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the following idiom:

When it rains, it pours (AE)/It never rains, but it pours (BE).

Comment: nice try, but missed the mark

Comment: Thanks Khan. You've really read between the lines what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

TRomano's ideas are good (especially "can of worms"; I hear that used frequently in IT systems contexts).

### Here are a few others that might apply in some situations.

If the project gets more difficult the more you look at the interconnected parts, it's like...

- **peeling the layers of an onion**
  http://www.google.com/search?q=layers+of+an+onion+metaphor&client=safari&hl=en&biw=320&bih=356&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIq9DE_dKMxgIVU3-SCh0K2wC9

  (This conveys both the sense that more is revealed the more you peel, and that it will smell so bad it might make you cry).

---

if, once you start taking things undone, it gets increasingly hard to put them back in order, it's like...

- **a Rubik's cube**
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik's_Cube

(or if it will be *impossible* to even put them back together...)

- **Humpty-Dumpty**
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty

---

If it's a complex structure held together by delicate links, which, if tinkered with,  could break and cause cascading problems, it will be like...

- **Dominoes falling**
  http://www.google.com/search?q=domino+falling&client=safari&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIoo7Y1tCMxgIVB0uSCh31DgBN&biw=320&bih=356

Or if tinkering might upset the balance and lead to a sudden collapse...

- **A house of cards**
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_cards

---

On the other hand, if the pieces are so tightly intertwined that it's impossible to pry one part loose without breaking the whole thing, you have ...

- **a Gordian Knot**
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot